# Adding data to ArrayList with the removal of old

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a small problem.

For example, I have `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Double> Temp1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

with size = 5 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). I need to move the data by 
removing one value when comes the new value. For example, when Temp1.add(5) I have to get a result (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Is it possible without using cycle?

Becuse In my app I have very big `ArrayList` (1000-15000 elements) that is filled from connected device with 5-10 items per sec. When I use the cycle "for" to retrieve last 50 items I lost productivity and receive from device 1-2 items per sec.

Comment: Can you switch to LinkedList?

Comment: You can replace by using this function: list.set( your_index, your_item );

Comment: Is the size fixed ? If so, you can use a fixed size array, and  `start` and `end` indexes to implement a circular array .It will be more efficient than a LinkedList (if size is fixed). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3R9-DkVtds

Comment: @Nyavro, Thanks. I have not used before. I'll try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Nyavro mentioned in his comment, you can use a `LinkedList` which implements the [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface.  Just add the new element to the tail and then pop the head.

```
List<Double> temp1 = new LinkedList<>();
temp1.add(5);
temp1.removeFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` function for replacing some value for example, you need to remove 1 from Arraylist and change this to 100 then do it like this

```
Temp1.set(1,100);
```

Here 1 is index and 100 is value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always want to remove first element,Right.then you can try this,
when you want to add new value,remove first by using,

```
Temp1.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21696680/642706) with [this correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21696750/642706), here's a list of the datastructures you can use :

- [`EvictingQueue`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html) in [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) 15
- [`CircularFifoQueue`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) in [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons)